# High order functions in C# which return void

Tags: c#, higher-order-functions

I am having some issues understanding HOF in C#. I want my DoSomething function to receive a function as a parameter that returns *void* and receives *two strings*. I cannot set the first generic parameter to void as the compiler complains. And this gives me an error.

Whats the right syntax to do this in C# ?

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        DoSomething((v1, v2) => Console.WriteLine(v1, v2));
    }
    
    private static void DoSomething(Func<string,string,string> f){
        f("1", "2");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for the lambda also: `DoSomething(Console.WriteLine)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Action<string, string>` instead of `Func<string, string, string>` basically. The `Action` delegates are declared to return `void`; the `Func` delegates are declared to return "the final type parameter".

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        DoSomething((v1, v2) => Console.WriteLine(v1, v2));
    }

    private static void DoSomething(Action<string, string> action)
    {
        action("1", "2");
    }
}
```

Note that here the result is just "1" because that's being interpreted as a format string. If you use `action("Value here: '{0}'", "some-value");` instead, you'll get output of `Value here: 'some-value'`.